# tableView backgroundView is not working in iOS7

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I am setting a view as a background for uitableview. View simply has colorWithPatternImage.

It is working correctly in iOS6, But in iOS7, it dont have any effect, TableView background remains just white in iOS7. I am using Three20 library.

My code is

```
UIImage *imgBackGround = [UIImage imageNamed: @"my_background.png"];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[backView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:imgBackGround]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = backView;
[backView release];
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:imgBackGround];
```

What can be issue in iOS7 ? 
Help please, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow, you are still using Three20 library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iOS 7, tableview's cell automatically have a white background color. You need to clear the cell's color and background.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView =  [UIView new];
```

Use in cellForRowAtIndexPath

This will surely solve it.